# Show that the system has a stable limit cycle for $\mu > 0$. What kind of bifurcation occurs at $\mu =0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am solving the following problem:

---

Consider a planar system

\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= \mu x + y\\
\dot{y} &= -x - y^3.
\end{align}

1. Show that the origin is a fixed point and perform its linear stability analysis for all values of $\mu$.
2. Show that the system has a stable limit cycle for $\mu > 0$. What kind of bifurcation occurs at $\mu = 0$.

---

I am having trouble with part 2. It looks like there should be a supercritical Hopf bifurcation for $\mu >0$ since we have a spiral that switches from stable to unstable at $\mu = 0$. I know that I need to find a trapping region containing the origin and neither of the other fixed points. I thought that converting to polar coordinates might be easier. The transformed system (assuming I calculated everything right) is:

\begin{align}
\dot{r} &= r^2[\mu\cos^2(\theta) - r^2\sin^4(\theta)]\\
\dot{\theta} &= -\big[1 + \frac{\sin(2\theta)}{2}(r^2\sin^2(\theta) + \mu)\big].
\end{align}

I think that, at least for $\mu$ small, this is possible, but there isn't an annulus available since $\theta = 0 \implies \dot{r} > 0$ for any $r \neq 0$. Any help would be greatly appreciated. My work for part 1 follows.

UPDATE(1): I think I almost have it. I ended up not using polar coordinates. Nullclines helped get most of the trapping region. I will post up the solution if I get it.

---

PART(1): We have the fixed points $\{ (0,0), (1/\mu^{3/2}, -1/\sqrt{\mu}), (-1/\mu^{3/2}, 1/\sqrt{\mu})\}$. The linearization of the system gives the following Jacobian:

$$
Df(x, y) = \begin{pmatrix} \mu & 1\\ -1 & -3y^2 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

We see that

\begin{align}
\text{tr}(Df(x, y)) = \mu -3y^2 &\implies \text{tr}(Df(0, 0)) = \mu\\
\text{det}(Df(x, y)) = 1 - 3\mu y^2 &\implies \text{det}(Df(0, 0)) = 1.
\end{align}

Also, note that at the origin

\begin{align}
\text{tr}^2 - 4\text{det} &= \mu^2 - 4\\
&= (\mu - 2)(\mu + 2).
\end{align}

Thus, we have the following characterization of the fixed point $(0, 0)$, depending on $\mu$:

\begin{align}
\mu < -2 &\implies \text{stable node}\\
\mu = -2 &\implies \text{stable degenerate}\\
-2 < \mu < 0 &\implies \text{stable spiral}\\
\mu = 0 &\implies \text{center}\\
0 < \mu < 2 &\implies \text{unstable spiral}\\
\mu = 2 &\implies \text{unstable degenerate}\\
2 < \mu &\implies \text{unstable node}.
\end{align}

For completeness, the other two fixed points only exist for $\mu > 0$ and are saddles for all values of $\mu > 0$.